# HDFview on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, hdf

After updating ubuntu to the newest version 18.04 I have problem with HDFview. I can open hdfview but I can't load any file. 
I terminal I have this warning:

> [warning] /usr/bin/hdfview: No java runtime was found

I quote some of info which I find: "It seems that Ubuntu 18.04 has a broken hdfview such that the program opens, but silently fails to read any HDF5/NetCDF4 files."

I know I can use alternative hdf-compass but I used to hdfview. Can I fix it in some way?

Comment: [Here](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=848257) a procedure that eliminates the warning by setting `JAVA_HOME` , but the file contents are not shown, which is the core of the problem.

Comment: This is a known bug by now. Not solved yet...